# Add-in express and BackGroundWorker threading

Tags: multithreading, backgroundworker, outlook-addin

Here's the problem:
I have an Outlook add-in made with add-in express.
It hosts a panel with the only winforms ElementHost, where WPF content is performing.
In this WPF control I have a textbox and button.
Button click triggers Backgroundworker to load info from database, in 'RunWorkerCompleted' process this data is being put into control.
When button is pressed - everything goes normally. But if I catch 'Enter' key press in textbox and then trigger BackgroundWorker - 'RunWorkerCompleted' is being launched not in the main thread, but in a thread pool, and cannot access WPF elements.
In both cases BackGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() is being called from Main thread, DoWork runs in thread pool, and only in case of enter-key-catch, RunWorkerCompleted also runs in a thread pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into a bug in Add-in Express. In some cases Add-in Express event handlers are called with `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` set to `null`. `BackgroundWorker` use it in `RunWorkerAsync` method to save the ui context, so that is the problem.

To fix SynchronizationContext you could use the following workaround. Here `MyAction` is the method where you call `RunWorkerAsync` from.

```
var ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
if (ctx != null)
{
    MyAction();
}
else
{
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += (s, a) =>
    {
        MyAction();
        timer.Stop();
        timer = null;
    };
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
    timer.Start();
}
```

Another solution would be saving the valid `SynchronizationContext.Current` value somewhere in a static member and then calling `SynchronizationContext.Post` in the event handler for the same purpose. I haven't tried this one though.

Comment: Thanks. I found it easier to with `WPFElement.Invoke(()=>{ui-related-code})`